# Hooking Send () recv()

Tags: c++

Ok i been playing around with some hooking again. I recently moved from studying php to c/c++ for several months now .
so i decided to do something about Hooking looking up some facts from msdn and some other things on here .

I try to inject this DLL into Firefox, when i do, i do not see it open the hookFile.txt and save the buffer to the .txt file, am i getting something wrong ?
my source code goes like this

"DLLHookSendRecv.h"

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ApiHook(LPSTR Module,LPCSTR OldFunc,LPVOID NewFunc,unsigned char *backup);
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void newSend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void newRecv(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Winsock.h>
#include "DLLHookSendRecv.h"

#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32")

typedef int (*WINAPI oldsend)(SOCKET s,const char* buf,int len,int flags);
typedef int (*WINAPI oldrecv)(SOCKET s,const char* buf,int len,int flags);

BYTE hook[6];

void ApiHook(LPSTR Module,LPCSTR OldFunc,LPVOID NewFunc,unsigned char *backup)
{
  DWORD dwProtect;
  HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibraryA(Module);
  DWORD OldFuncAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(hLib,OldFunc);
  DWORD NewFuncAddr = (DWORD)NewFunc;

  BYTE jmp[6] ={0xE9,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xC3};
  DWORD  jmpAddr = (NewFuncAddr - OldFuncAddr) -5;
  memcpy(&jmp[1],&jmpAddr,4);

  VirtualProtect((LPVOID) OldFuncAddr,6,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&dwProtect);
  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(),(LPVOID)OldFuncAddr,jmp,6,0);
  VirtualProtect((LPVOID)OldFuncAddr,6,dwProtect,&dwProtect);
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void newSend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
   FILE* logFile;
   logFile = fopen("hookFile.txt","w");
   fprintf(logFile,"%s",buf);
   fclose(logFile);
  return send(s,buf,len,flags);
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void newRecv(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
   FILE* logFile;
   logFile = fopen("hookFile.txt","w");
   fprintf(logFile,buf);
   fclose(logFile);
  return recv(s,buf,len,flags);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDLL,DWORD ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
  switch(ul_reason_for_call)
  {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      ApiHook("ws2_32.dll","send",newSend,hook);
      ApiHook("ws2_32.dll","recv",newRecv,hook);
    break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
      ApiHook("ws2_32.dll","send",newSend,hook);
      ApiHook("ws2_32.dll","recv",newRecv,hook);
    break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
  }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that FireFox doesn't call `send` or `receive`. Is there any reason why you'd suspect that they should call precisely those functions?

Comment: "Doesnt Call"... You mean instead of using _declspec i use _stdcall? could this be the problem? i obviosuly do not have suspicion , was thinking being Firefox , should have send() and recv() function capabilities already, i was just calling the functions with the buf parameter to log traffic data ... nothing else.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. It makes no sense at all to change `__declspec` to `__stdcall`, as those two keywords are entirely unrelated. If you want to successfully hook functions, you should know what both keywords mean. Also, when you say "recv() function capability", you're confusing "receive data capability"  and "`recv` function".

Comment: Just dont know what to think again, still looking out to see what the problem is. some related topics i see here most advise to use _stdcall other than that, thats what got me very confused. How Do you Call the functions ... thats another thing to Ask

Answer (score 0):

Actaully Firefox doesnt send or recv any packet.(if you are asking for application) use `plugin_container` instead of firefox(which is actually sending and recvin packets). If you didnt update ur flash player to newest than u have look for second `plugin_container` process in the process list.

You can check which process sending and recving packets via packet tools like `WPE` or `rPE` :) have a good day

Answer (score 0):

hmm... i worked games (especially flash games) on firefox and when i try to trace packets via dissambler,debugger or packet read tools, Firefox itself never calls `send` and `recv` but when i use second `plugin-container.exe` on the process list, it actually show me some packets. Sometimes `plugin-container.exe` uses `winsock 1.0` and sometime it uses `Winsock 2.0 (WSASend,WSARecv)`. The reason behind this is prob. Firefox handles extensions via `plugin-container.exe` such as `Flash Player`,`Shockwave Player` or `Java` etc. so firefox itself doesnt need to call these function. The apps within these extensions would call winsock instead of firefox. 
 This is just an approach of mine. Have good days